# How to upgrade to Swift 4 with Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, swift4, xcode10

Currently i am using Swift 3.x and I made code compatible to Xcode 10 with swift 3.x

So how to convert to Swift 4.0 with Xcode 10 as there is only option Convert to Current Syntax

I am trying following two way:

**1. Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax...**

**2. Conversion to Swift 4.2 is available**

Comment: Swift 4 and 4.2 both are almost same. Also Since you decided to convert your codebase, I recommend you to use latest Swift version 4.2 to avoid conversions in future.

Comment: Why do you want 4.0 specifically instead of the most current version?

Comment: Make sure you have updated xCode then under Build Settings, check the drop down options for Swift Compiler - Language.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that, you only want to upgrade to particular version from your current version. Please check this link below. You can do what you are expecting.And it wont convert totally to upgrade version through converter. If your have more files, it bit you to check which is deprecated and which is available on your upgrade version.If you want to change only some particular syntax, please post here.So that other can help you out.

> https://medium.com/@hanif.awan2007/tips-upgrading-your-code-from-swift-3-to-swift-4-dbcba128b48b